# Using electron to access cross-origin-resources

Tags: sharepoint-2010, cors, electron

I have a list on sharepoint where I am tracking tasks.

I am trying to create an electron app that will ping (http get request) this list every minute or so and display a little window with all the tasks the current user has assigned and highlight new tasks.

I am using the fetch API to access the list as follows:

```
const _COLLAB_ROOT = "http://company.com/projects/team-site/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/"

export function read(list, callback) {
    const myHeaders = new Headers({
        "Accept": "application/json",
        'Authorization': 'Basic '+btoa('username:password'),
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    });
    const myInit = {
        method: 'GET',
        headers: myHeaders,
        mode: 'no-cors'
    }
    fetch(_COLLAB_ROOT+list,myInit)
        .then(response => {
            if (response.ok) {
                response.json().then(data => {
                    callback(data.d);
                });
            }
            return Promise.reject(Error('error'))
        }).catch(error => {
            return Promise.reject(Error(error.message))
        })
}
```

Other module:

```
read('listname',data => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

However when I send this request with  a list name filled in, I get the following:
[image]
[image]

Now I assume this has something to do with CORS. What I would like to know is, is there a way to get this working?

It seems like something very obvious to be required in electron.

Also I have set the we-preferences property to

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: true,
    'web-preferences': {'web-security': false}
  });
```

Any help is appreciated here.
I will be really surprised if this is not possible so hopefully I am being dumb!

Edit: Response when querying from Restlet client on chrome[image]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're using the old webPreferences syntax, your constructor should look something this :)

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 800,
    height: 600,
    frame: true,
    webPreferences: {
        webSecurity: false
    }
});
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestion - still getting 401 Unauthorized though.

Comment: 401 Unauthorized isn't something you can bypass client side, webSecurity disables things like CORS protection and iframe sandboxing rules.  401 responses are generated server side so you are probably missing some kind of authentication token required by the server.

Comment: Hey, thanks - I tried this request in a rest client for chrome and it works just fine though. Will add details to OP

Comment: In Chrome you probably already have a session for this website and any Chrome app / extension will use that existing session when sending the request.  Ensure you are signed out of anything to do with this URL and you will see the same error.

You can also just try with incognito mode and see what happens :)

Comment: Ok, so if that is correct does that mean I am missing something in my query?

Comment: Almost certainly some kind of Cookie or authentication header

Comment: Ok, I've been searching through as much info as I can online but getting nowhere. Any idea?

Comment: I'll accept the answer above based on the title of the question - because this actually solved the problem in the question title!  My real issue it turns out, is authenticating a REST call to SharePoint 2010 list

Comment: `webSecurity` no longer controls CORS. See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23664#issuecomment-692422997

Answer (score 1):

It seems that it is not possible right now, since `webSecurity` no longer controls CORS. (**for v9+**)

> The webSecurity option controls the web security inside blink, but
> recently the control of CORS has been moved out of blink and thus the
> option no longer controls CORS.

See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23664#issuecomment-692422997

Comment: then what's the solution? is that anyway we can disable it ?

Comment: @MohamedJakkariya This is a browser (chromium) restriction, so you cannot do anything. Only you can set your APIs to allow cross-origin requestes (or ask API owner to implement it)

Comment: yeah, I'm facing an issue on Nginx. I found it and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

> only  suitable for development

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({width: 900, height: 680,webPreferences: {
nodeIntegration: true,
webSecurity: false
}});
```

Comment: A little explanation with that bit of code would be helpful to others who find this in  the future.

Comment: `webSecurity` no longer controls CORS. See https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/23664#issuecomment-692422997